# How can I retrieve the instrumentation key for an Application Insights instance in an Azure Resource Group Template?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

Is there any way to retrieve the Instrumentation Key for an Application Insights instance in an Azure Resource Group template ?

I've tried the instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-functions/) to retrieve the list of list* operations available on Azure resources, but `Microsoft.Insights/components` doesn't appear in the list anywhere. It's making me think that retrieving an Instrumentation Key in the template isn't currently possible

Answer (score 61, accepted):

After some digging and experimenting, this is what I found works:

```
"outputs": {
    "MyAppInsightsInstrumentationKey": {
        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('myAppInsightsInstanceName')), '2014-04-01').InstrumentationKey]",
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

Comment: You may also be able to use the `listKeys()` function pointed at the Insights instance name: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-functions/#listkeys I had a similar question for the Log Analytics/OMS/OpsInsight Workspace Primary & Secondary SharedKeys, and while the resourceProvider does not contain and list* operations as that blog indicates is required, it still was able to return back my keys.

Comment: @Alex-Marshall, this is helpful.  Is there any chance you could address this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37570408/188474

Answer (score 9):

Try it (using azure cli)

```
az resource show -g $RESOURCE_GROUP -n $APP_INSIGHTS --resource-type "microsoft.insights/components" --query properties.InstrumentationKey
```

Comment: Brilliant! Especially since `az monitor app-insights api-key show ...` doesn't expose it.

Comment: This approach also includes connection string. 

Answer (score 5):

Instrumentation Key belongs to resource, you can find it in Azure Resource manager template. If you want to find Instrumentation Key, you need to define ResourceType to Microsoft.Insights/components. Try the below code:

`$resourcevalue=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName Default-ApplicationInsights-*** -ResourceType Microsoft.Insights/components -ResourceName **hdinsights -ApiVersion 2015-05-01
$resourcevalue.Properties.InstrumentationKey`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to retrieve the key in the template itself so that it can be automatically populated into application settings in the portal.

Comment: Your snippet returned a empty `Properties` property. For me the following worked: `( Get-AzApplicationInsights ).InstrumentationKey`

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Alex Marshall will work fine, but I just wanted to contribute by saying you could do this with Bicep as well. The syntax would be as follows:

```
resource appInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' existing = {
  name: 'appinsights-name'
  scope: resourceGroup('rg-appinsights-resides-in')
}


output appString string = appInsights.properties.ConnectionString
output appinsight string = appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
```