# I need to retrieve the Application Insights's InstrumentationKey using C# code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-rm-template

I have created the application Insights using ARM template with C# code.

```
var creds = new AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(client, key, tenant, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            
IAzure azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Authenticate(creds).WithSubscription(subscription);

IDeployment deployement = azure.Deployments.Define("my-app")
                    .WithExistingResourceGroup("my-rg-grp")
                    .WithTemplate(template)
                    .WithParameters("{}")
                    .WithMode(DeploymentMode.Incremental)
                    .CreateAsync();
```

deployment doesn't have the InstrumentationKey in response.

**How could I get the InstrumentationKey just after the Application Insights creation using ARM?**

Comment: did you add the instrumentation key as an output in your template?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724938/1537195

Comment: @silent Thanks... I didn't added the instrumentation key as an output in my template. After adding it to the template I am getting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ApplicationInsightsManagementClient` class to get the ApplicationInsights resources and the relevant property. The class is defined at [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights v0.3.0-preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.applicationinsights.management.applicationinsightsmanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet-preview) package

```
ApplicationInsightsManagementClient applicationInsightsManagementClient = 
                         new ApplicationInsightsManagementClient(creds) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };

var appliationInsightComponents = await applicationInsightsManagementClient.Components.ListAsync();

var requiredApplicationInsightComponent = appliationInsightComponents.SingleOrDefault(a => 
          a.ApplicationId.Equals("<<Name of resource>>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

// to get the InstrumentationKey use

`requiredApplicationInsightComponent.InstrumentationKey`